# Solving a recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=(n+1)\cdot a_n-1$

Tags: proof-writing, recurrence-relations

$$ a_{n+1}=(n+1)\cdot a_n-1$$

$a_1=1$

I need help solving the above recurrence relation. Any hint or solution would be helpful.

Thank You

Comment: Okay, $a_1=1$. Now please compute the first few values and search [the OEIS](http://oeis.org).

Comment: @NoName - please see the edit

Comment: @Somos - oeis shows it ceil((3-e)*n!), but how to solve it

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "how to solve it". At least the OEIS gave you useful information.

Comment: Similar equation here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550562/find-the-formula-for-the-sequence-a-n-that-satisfies-the-recurrence-relation/2550705#2550705 When you see $a_{n+1}=(n+k)a_n$ then set $a_n=(n+k)!\,b_n$ to solve you will get a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\,b_n = a_n / n!\,$ so that $\,a_n = n! \cdot b_n\,$, then:

$$b_{n+1} = b_n - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} = b_{n-1} - \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} = \cdots = b_1 - \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!}$$

The latter sum does not have a "nice" closed form, but can be expressed in terms of the [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), [using](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1+%2F+k!+for+k+%3D+0+to+n):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} = \frac{e \cdot \Gamma(n+1, 1)}{n!}
$$

So in the end: $\;\;a_n = n! \cdot b_n = 3 \cdot n! - e \cdot \Gamma(n+1, 1)\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}a_{n+1}&=(n+1)a_n-1\\&=(n+1)\{na_{n-1}-1\}-1\\&=(n+1)na_{n-1}-(n+1)-1\\&=(n+1)n\{(n-1)a_{n-2}-1\}-(n+1)-1\\&=(n+1)n(n-1)a_{n-2}-(n+1)n-(n+1)-1\\&=\cdots\\&=(n+1)!\cdot a_1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\prod_{k=0}^i(n+1-k)-1\end{align}$$